# is this a good use for django internationalisation

Tags: django, internationalization

I am working on a django website/project, it has already been internationalised/localised to us-english, gb-english and mandarin.

It is deployed with same codebase except for the settings config which states what lang to use. Some deployments are mandarin only, others are us-english.

The client now has a requirement to change some of the language used within a gb-english version for a specific deployment. My main goal is not to duplicate things and I think I can get what I need out of django 18n.

Basically, I am looking to find if i can or should use django i18n to handle:

'Welcome' on deployA

'Oh hai' on deployB,

even though they're still both gb-english based sites, I feel I should be able to say that deployA will use 'en_GB' and deployB would use 'en_GB_special'.

I suppose it's the fact that I want to use a non-standard i18n name/code that is making me wonder if I should do this, or if I am approaching this in the wrong manner.

Comment: There is actually a standard for creating your own [language tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).  It's called "private use subtags" and it's specified in [RFC 5646](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646#page-18).  You could use `en-x-special` or `en-x-lol`for example, if you decide to create a custom language.

Answer (score 1):

I would only create a new language if you're intending to maintain two translations.  If the new site will need to stay in sync with en_GB and/or you intend to use the customization in another language then I think you'd be better off creating new messages, adding a string for them to en_GB and add a flag to your application to switch the feature for your feline client.

Comment: "feline client", I see what you did there. +1

Comment: Thanks for the advice Colin. It feels like I need to create a psuedo-localised version of the en_gb message file, but as I probably only need to change a few keys, I would want it to fallback to en_gb. A flag in the code would do it, but I was wondering if that could be avoided (as I don't know how many places or parts will eventually need a flag like this)